# How do I put a map in the background and make a carousel from the menu at the bottom?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How do I put a map in the background and make a carousel from the menu at the bottom?
First view:
[image]

Second view:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure you've described can be achieved with Xamarin.Forms with easy. I'm presenting one possibility, it's likely that there are more.

You could just employ an `AbsoluteLayout` with your map taking the whole space and a `CarouselView` that is overlayn, taking the lower third or so of your page.

I've created a small demo for that. The XAML of my page is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MapTest.MainPage">

    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightBlue" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"></BoxView>
        <CarouselView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,.3" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>View 1</x:String>
                    <x:String>View 2</x:String>
                    <x:String>View 3</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="20" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Please note that you'll have to add

```cs
Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
```

in your `MainActivity`/`AppDelegate` before `Forms.Init()` is called, since `CollectionView` (on which `CarouselView` is based) is a preview (you could also use a third party component for that, but for sake of simplicity I've used the built in Xamarin.Forms view).

This is the result I've achieved with my layout

[image: Demo of the code in action]